# How to solve the following special inequality?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, modules, exponential-function

Find $k$, as a function of $d_2$ and $d_3$, such that:

$$\left \vert { d_2 \left [ \sin(e^{d_3\,y}) - \sin(e^{d_3\,x})\right] + (x-y) d_2 d_3 e^{d_3\,z} \cos(e^{d_3\,z})} \right \vert \le k (\vert{x-z}\vert + \vert{y-z}\vert) \,\vert{x-y}\vert$$

Comment: hell of the inequality :D

Comment: hell of what? i voted it as an useful comment because this comment makes me laugh. i do not know why

Comment: I see that k appears only on RHS. Why don't you divide the inequality by the number multiplied by k

Answer (score 1):

Without further restrictions, there can be no such $k$. As $z\to\infty$ (if $d_3>0$) or $z\to-\infty$ (if $d_3<0$) the $\limsup$ the left side is $\Theta(e^{d_3z})$, whereas the right side is $\Theta(|z|)$.